# When does $\|f*g\|_{p}=\|f\|_{1}\|g\|_{p}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, inequality, lp-spaces, convolution

From *Rudin, Real and Complex Analysis, 1st edition, Chapter 7, Problem 4*

Suppose $1\le p\le \infty$, $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{1})$, $g\in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{1})$. Show that the the integral defining $f*g$ exists for almost all $x$, that $f*g\in L^{p}$, and that $$\|f*g\|_{p}\le \|f\|_{1}\|g\|_{p}.$$

Show that the equality can hold if $p=1$ and if $p=\infty$, and find conditions under which this happens. Assume $1<p<\infty$, and equality holds, then either $f=0$ a.e or $g=0$ a.e.

**My thoughts:**

By Fubini's theorem we can prove $$\|f*g\|_{p}^{p}\le \|f\|_1^{p} \|g\|_p^{p}$$ So the first claim is okay. But I do not know how to show when the equality holds.

So it suffice to prove $$\int\left(\int f(x-y)g(y)dy\right)^{p}dx<\left(\int |f|dx\right)^{p}\left(\int |g|^{p}dy\right)$$

By Fubini's theorem we have \begin{align}\int\left(\int f(x-y)g(y)dy\right)^{p}dx&\le \int (\int |f(x-y)|^{p}|g(y)|^{p}dy)dx\\&=\left(\int |g(y)|^p dy)(\int |f(x-y)| dx\right)^{p-1}\int |f(x-y)|dy\\&=\int |g(y)^p|dy (\int |f(t)|dt)^{p}
\end{align} using Lebesgue measure's translation invariance. Since the first inequality is just from absolute value, we may assume $f,g$ are non-negative without losing any generality. But I do not see which one of the last few equalities is just an inequality.

Comment: Here's how: look at each inequality that you used in the proof of $\|f*g\|_p \le \|f\|_1\|g\|_p$ separately, and ask yourself: when does equality hold here?

Comment: Let me expand the details and you may comment.

Comment: Now updated with the "proof".

Comment: Your comments after the proof are exactly backwards. Equalities are equalities, there is nothing to discuss there. They cannot turn into strict inequalities. We must find out when the first inequality turns into equality. No, it's not "just from absolute value". And no, you can't say "non-negative without losing any generality" when considering the equality cases.

Comment: I see. So the first inequality is the problem. Yes I am at a loss when (and why) it is true.

Comment: Hm, it seems that "By Fubini's theorem we can prove" is not such a great proof after all. You really need to think more of why Young's inequality is true to begin with, before you can move on to the equality case.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I suspected. But Rudin did not prove Young's inequality at all in his book. I need to take a look.

Comment: In the 3rd edition he proves the case $p=1$ and leaves the general case as an exercise. If you run out of ideas, [the proof is here](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~peterseb/mth627/docs/627w2004-convolution.pdf)

Comment: @PavelM: I found the proof by reading Young's inequality's section on Folland. Thanks nevertheless.

Comment: you  not agree with this answer? see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432208/fy-x-integrable-implies-f-0-a-e

Answer (score 0):

Here we assume $f$ and $g$ to be positive functions. 
**Here is my result:**
if $$\|f*g\|_{p}=\|f\|_{1}\|g\|_{p} $$ then either 
$g=0~~a.e$ or $p =\infty$ or $f=0~~~a.e$.

**see all the details below.**

> **Claim:** for, $f\in L^1$ and $g\in L^p$ we have, for all $x\in\Bbb R,$ $$x\mapsto h(x) =\|f\|_1^{p-1} |g|^p*|f|(x)-|f*g(x)|^p \ge 0.$$

**proof:** By [Holder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality)

\begin{align}|f*g(x)|&\le \int_\Bbb R |g(y)||f(x-y)|^{1/p} |f(x-y)|^{1-1/p}dy\\
&\le \left(\int_\Bbb R |g(y)|^p|f(x-y)|dy\right)^{1/p}\left( \int_\Bbb R |f(x-y)|dy\right)^{1-1/p}\\&=\left[\|f\|_1^{p-1} |g|^p*|f|(x)\right]^{1/p}\end{align}
That is $$\color{red}{h(x)= \|f\|_1^{p-1} |g|^p*|f|(x)-|f*g(x)|^p \ge 0~~~\forall ~~x\in\Bbb R. }$$

However, by Fubini,

\begin{align}\|f*g\|_{p}=\|f\|_{1}\|g\|_{p} &\Longleftrightarrow \int_\Bbb R |g*f(x)|^{p} dx =  \|f\|_1^{p-1}\left(\int_\Bbb R |g(y)|^p\right)\left(\int_\Bbb R |f(x-y)|dy\right)\\ &\Longleftrightarrow \int_\Bbb R |g*f(x)|^{p} dx =  \|f\|_1^{p-1}\int_\Bbb R \left(\int_\Bbb R |g(y)|^p|f(x-y)|dy\right)dx
\\ &\Longleftrightarrow \int_\Bbb R |g*f(x)|^{p} dx =  \|f\|_1^{p-1}\int_\Bbb R [|g|^p*|f|](x)dx
\\ &\Longleftrightarrow \int_\Bbb R |g*f(x)|^{p}- \|f\|_1^{p-1}[|g|^p*|f|](x)dx=0
\\ &\Longleftrightarrow \int_\Bbb R h(x)dx=0
\end{align}

But since $h\ge 0$ We conclude that

\begin{align}\|f*g\|_{p}=\|f\|_{1}\|g\|_{p} &\Longleftrightarrow 
h(x)=0~~a.e\\ 
 &\Longleftrightarrow \color{blue}{|g*f(x)|^{p} =\|f\|_1^{p-1}[|g|^p*|f|](x)~~a.e}\\
 &\Longleftrightarrow \color{blue}{\int_\Bbb R g(y)f(x-y)dy =\left(\int_\Bbb Rf(x-y)dy\right)^{1-1/p}\left(\int_\Bbb Rg^p(y)f(x-y)dy\right)^{1/p}~~a.e}\tag{I}
\end{align}

**On the other hands, in any measure space,** the [Holder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) says:
$$\int_E|f_1f_2|\leq\left(\int_E|f_1|^a\right)^{\frac{1}{a}}\left(\int_E|f_2|^a\right)^{\frac{1}{b}}$$
where $\displaystyle\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=1$. **Equality holds when $\alpha |f_1|^a=\beta |f_2|^b$ almost everywhere on $E$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants.**

> Thus, let $x\in \Bbb R$  **fixed** such that 
>   $$\color{blue}{|g*f(x)|^{p} =\|f\|_1^{p-1}[|g|^p*|f|](x)}$$ 
>   we consider $f\in L^1$ we consider, the measure 
>   $$\color{red}{d\mu_x(y)= |f(x-y)|dy}$$
>   **$(\Bbb R, \mathcal{B}, \mu_x)$ is a measure space,**

It springs from (I) that, 
\begin{align}
 &\int_\Bbb R g(y)f(x-y)dy =\left(\int_\Bbb Rf(x-y)dy\right)^{1-1/p}\left(\int_\Bbb Rg^p(y)f(x-y)dy\right)^{1/p}~\\
 &\Longleftrightarrow \\
& \int_\Bbb R g(y)d\mu_x(y) =\left(\int_\Bbb R \mathbf1_\Bbb R(y)d\mu_x(y)\right)^{1-1/p}\left(\int_\Bbb Rg^p(y)d\mu_x(y)\right)^{1/p}
\end{align}

Applying Holder inequality above there exists a constant $C_x$ such that,
$$g(y) =C_x ~~\mu_x-~~a.e$$

**Improvement:**

> Then there exists $A\subset \Bbb R. $
>   such that, $$ g(y) =C_x~~~ \forall ~~y\in\Bbb R\setminus A$$ and $$\mu_x(A) = 0~~\Longleftrightarrow  \int_A  |f(x-y)|dy= 0$$
>   Then, either $|A_x|= 0$ ($A_x$ is Lebesgue negligible ) or $A_x$ is not Lebesgue negligible and  $f(x-y) = 0 ~~~a.e $ on $A$.

**Assume that: $|A_x|=0$** then obviously we get that

$$g(y) =C_x~~a.e~~on~~\Bbb R$$

which means that $g$ is constant almost everywhere. since the only function satisfying $f(x) = h(y)$ for almost all $x$ and $y$ are constant function.
Thus, we either have, $\color{red}{g =0~~a.e}$ or $\color{red}{p =\infty}$ since, $\color{red}{g\in L^p(\Bbb R)}$

Now **Assume that:  $A_x$ is not Lebesgue negligible Then,  $f(x-y) = 0 ~~~a.e $ on $A_x$.**

Then repeating this argument for all $x\in\Bbb R$ we arrive at $f= 0~~a.e$

Or use this to conclude [$f(y-x)$ integrable implies $f=0$ a.e.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432208/fy-x-integrable-implies-f-0-a-e)

Comment: It's not clear what your last sentence are supposed to mean?

Comment: Yes I have stuck there to find the contradiction. if you find it help please. But I hope What I have written till there correct

Comment: Do you mean you "can't" find the contradiction?

Comment: Yes ! but My feeling is that we must have, $g(y)= Kf(x)$ for all most every $x$ and $y$. but this statement need some strong arguments. this will leads to the contradiction but I how to justifies

Comment: @JohnMa  Hello I have updated the answer please read and tell me whether you agree of not? thanks in advance