# $f(y-x)$ integrable implies $f=0$ a.e.

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

If $f(y-x)$ is in $L^p(\mathbb R^d\times\mathbb R^d)$, then I seem to conclude that $f=0$ a.e. (which seems wrong). My reasoning is that by Fubini and the integral's shift invariance (assume $p=1$ for convenience)
$$\infty>\iint|f(y-x)|dydx = \int\left( \int |f(y-x)|dy\right) dx =  \int\left( \int |f(y)|dy\right) dx = \int \text{const}\ dx $$ The const is non-negative but can't be positive else the right hand side will diverge, thus const $=0$. But this implies that $f=0$.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Doesn't seem wrong to me.

Comment: *Where am I going wrong?* Nowhere, actually. Sorry.

Comment: So every function of this form is zero? That's strange because I have a question from a past exam asking to prove that the operator $Tf(x)=\int K(|y-x|)f(y)dy$ where $K\in L^1$, $|K|<M$ satisfies that its spectrum spans $L^2$. So simply all of $L^2$ is an eigenvector (of eigenvalue $0$) therefore spans itself?

Comment: Where did everyone go?

Comment: I think a 34-minute gap between your comments, when it's the middle of the night in North America, on a site where people volunteer their time to assist you, is something you can put up with.

Comment: @bjorne There is a difference between the function $x\mapsto K(x)$  being integrable on $\mathbb R^d$ and the function $(x,y)\mapsto K(x-y)$ being integrable on $\mathbb R^d\times \mathbb R^d$. The former is true for all $L^1$ functions; the latter is true only for functions that are zero a.e.

Comment: Indeed, the question says the latter (I paraphrased inappropriately): $K(|x-y|)\in L^1(\mathbb R^d \times \mathbb R^d)$

Comment: @bjorne Then I guess the question writer made a mistake. Happens often. ... By the way, the likely reason neither Giuseppe Negro nor Did replied to your later comment is that they did not see it. The  `@` feature can be used to notify people of subsequent comments: [see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/224469).

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, your reasoning is correct and as ˈjuː.zɚ79365 said:

> There is a difference between the function $x\mapsto K(x)$ being integrable on $\mathbb R^d$ and the function $(x,y)\mapsto K(x−y)$ being integrable on $\mathbb R^d\times \mathbb R^d$. The former is true for all $L^1$ functions; the latter is true only for functions that are zero a.e.